# Display "Order Again" button on My Account pages regardless of order status in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Under the View Order pages in My Account in WooCommerce, I want to display the Order Again button regardless of if the order's been completed or not. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Updated my answer: I am sorry but the woocommerce native core function `order_again()` only works for completed orders.